# Fsharp.Chart: Data series labels in StackedColumn chart

Tags: charts, f#, stacked-chart

I want to draw a conventional stacked chart, with a legend showing what the colours mean, but what I get is a legend box showing lots of names of the form "Stacked_GenericChart_Series_1_4"

The standard way of creating the chart (by giving the constructor a 'a*'b seq seq) doesn't seem to have any way of setting the series names, either before or after the chart has been created.  On the other hand, the old-fashioned way (explained at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlnol/archive/2011/10/27/fsharpchart-release-supporting-stacked-charts-version-0-60.aspx), which would enable me to add a name to every chart, doesn't work at all with the current chart library, because the current one won't take a 'a*'b seq.

I note the source shows a constructor parameter called "Labels", but it's commented out.

There must be some way to set a chart's labels!  Where should I be looking?